# Sprite not remove from scene iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm making a JewelDash type game. For some reason after a while, 1 sprite which was supposed to be removed from the scene didn't. That sprite won't respond to touch, nothing, it just there. Hangout underneath other newly created sprites. What might be the cause of this?

I added all my sprites into a spritesArray. Whenever user touch a block, I loop through spritesArray and identify which sprite was touched. The fact that it doesn't respond to touch telling me that it was removed from spritesArray

This happens when many sprites get removed at the same time. And rarely happen.

Thanks.

Comment: What framework are you using here? iOS doesn't itself know anything about sprites. Cocos2D?

Comment: yes, i'm using cocos2d.

Comment: If you remove it from your array, you also need to remove it as child. Sounds like that part failed. Post the code.

Answer (score 1):

it may happen that you haven't alloc init spritesArray if you are using NSMuttableArray so alloc init it in init method before adding any sprite some time this happened with me so i cannot access any sprite because the array is not initialised. i get my array nil

also remove child from self like

```
[spritesArray removeObject:sprite name];
[self removeChild:sprite name cleanup:YES];
```

try this it may help